# YQL "The current table has been blocked”

Tags: web-scraping, yahoo, yql

I'm trying to query my self-written YQL-table. If I run the table from the YQL Console, everything works fine. But if I call the table by URL via browser or application, the following error appears:

The current table 'yahoo.finance.quant' has been blocked. It exceeded the allotted quotas of either time or instructions

The documentation says, 1.000 queries an hour are allowed. I definitely didn't exceed that limit. Does anyone have an idea how to resolve that?

And if not, is there any good alternative to YQL?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775339/yql-problem-the-current-table-has-been-blocked